# не удается задать ширину модального окна у bootstrap-vue

Tags: bootstrap, vue.js, modal

Как задать ширину модального окна у bootstrap-vue?

Вызываю модальное окно`<b-modal ref="modalOne" id="modalOne" size="lg"> </b-modal>`

Но само окошко мне нужно шире, пытался так, но ничего не выходит:

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
@media (min-width: 992px)
    .modal-lg
        max-width: 900px;
</style>
```

В документации ничего не нашел. Как правильно?

Comment: ты же прописываешь максимальную ширину, а пробовал ли ты просто width прописать?

Comment: Да, без результатно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yqx6pvwxox) `--> Modal.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-btn v-b-modal.myModal>Show Modal</b-btn>

    <b-modal id="myModal"> Hello From My Modal! </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

```
<style>
.modal-dialog {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 1.75rem auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 1.75rem auto;
  }
}
</style>
```

Все работает. Попробуйте обновить страницу, почистить кеш.

Comment: хмм.... действительно работает, но не  у меня. Скорее всего дело действительно кэше. Спасибо за ответ =)

Comment: по крайней мере у меня вот в codesandbox частенько зависает и нужно с очисткой кеша перезагрузить всю страницу) тогда помогает и либо начинает работать, либо ошибки выдает почему не работает)))

Comment: В общем сброс кэша не особо помог, но после перезагрузки вебпака все заработало как надо, это был просто локальный глюк. Еще раз спасибо.